# Do the different methods of creating classes in Javascript have names and what are they?

Tags: javascript

I've seen Javscript classes created all of these different ways:

---

```
function Thing() {

   method1: function() {

   },
   method2: function() {

   }   
}
```

**Method 1**

---

```
var thing = {

   method1: function() {

   },
   method2: function() {

   }   
};
```

**Method 2**

---

```
function Thing() {

}

Thing.prototype.method1 = function() {

}

Thing.prototype.method2 = function() {

}
```

**Method 3**

---

```
var thing = (function(){
   var b={};

   b.method1 = function(){

   };

   b.method2 = function class2(){

   };

   return b;
}());
```

**Method 4**

---

Do these different methods class of declaration have names, and what are they?  Also have I missed any methods?

Comment: Some of them yes. For example Method 1 is called "Syntax error". Method 2 - simple Object literal. Method 3 - usual "Prototypical pattern".  Method 4 - module pattern basically.

Comment: Mind your terminology - JavaScript is not Java. There's only one definitive way of creating 'classes' in JavaScript, and that's the ES6 `class` keyword, which is syntactical sugar. JavaScript remains a prototypical language. _It's objects all the way down._

Comment: You might want to check my answer to this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832784/understanding-public-private-instance-variables/31834214#31834214

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's look at things you asked about which are not actually methods to make classes.

If you only need one object with methods, but no class, you can create an **object literal**.

```
var myObject = {
  varname: value,
  varname: value,
  methodname: function() {
     // do something
  },
  methodname: function() {
     // do something
  }
};
```

This is rarely useful, but it creates a single instance with its own variables, some of which are functions. Note that in JS, there is no difference between a property and a method. A method is just a property of type `function`.

Variables created inside a function with the `var` keyword are only available inside the function. People who make libraries often wrap their whole code in a **closure** in the form of a self-executing function, so that any temporary variables no longer exist at the end of the code:

```
(function(){
  // code here
}());
```

---

Now to make a class in JS, you only need to create a constructor function. You can store properties in the created instance with the `this` keyword.

```
function MyClass(param) {
  this.value = param;
}

var instance = new MyClass("example");
```

A function is a block of code stored in an object. You can store functions inside variables like anything else, so you can also store functions inside objects.

```
function MyClass() {
  this.myMethod = function() {
    alert("hi");
  };
}
```

But since all instances of your class will need to run the same code, it isn't efficient to create the function inside the constructor. That will make a new copy of the function for each instance you create. So instead of doing this, we store the function in the prototype of the object.

Whenever you type say, `instance.someproperty`, the JS engine looks at `instance` to see if it has a property called `someproperty`. If it doesn't, it tries to look at `instance`'s prototype to see if it has a property of that name. And if it doesn't, it tries to look at that prototype's prototype... and so on, until it reaches the top of the chain.

So if you store the function in `MyClass.prototype.myMethod`, you will be able to call it with `instance.myMethod` and there will only be one copy of the function shared by all instances.

```
function MyClass(param) {
  this.value = param;
}

MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function() {
  alert(this.value);
};
```

There is one good reason to put functions inside the constructor instead of using the **prototype chain**: making pseudo-private variables and getter/setter functions. [See more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832784/understanding-public-private-instance-variables/31834214#31834214)

As for how to name those two ways of binding methods to an object, functions declared inside the constructor are **privileged methods** while those declared with the **prototype pattern** are called **public methods**. You can use both on a single class.

Comment: And although possibly beyond the scope of the question methods added directly to the constructor function are essentially static methods
`function Thing() { /*returns a new thing*/};
Thing.someStaticFn = function(){};
Thing.someStaticFn(); //static method of 'class' Thing.`

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, Method 1 is not valid `js`. Method 1 should probably be written as

```
function thing() {
    return {
        method1: function(){},
        method2: function(){}
    }
}
```

known as a *factory function*, calling it (like any normal function) produces objects with the specified properties. However, every object has its *own* copy of everything (which is probably unnecessary) so method 3 places shared functionality (methods, constants, etc) into the function's prototype. All of the objects created by calling the function (should be called with the `new` keyword in contrast to the factory function) will have access to the properties attached to their constructor's prototype (but will all share a pointer to the same property rather than their own copy).

Method 2 is just creating an object literal with the desired attributes, not a 'class' at all.

Method 4 is also not really a 'class' (in any sense of the term) it is known as the *Module Pattern* and uses a lexical closure to encapsulate the functionality revealing a public API through the returned object/function.

Its also worth reiterating as pointed out above that none of these are truly classes, the ES 6 `class` keyword is syntactic sugar for method 3.

Comment: Method 2 isn't a factory function, it's not even a function!

Comment: Youre right I'm having trouble telling wich is which because the headings come after the code. Fixed

Comment: Good. Thumbs up for thinking about factory methods too.