# Detect the caller and called it

Tags: javascript

I want to recognize the calling function and one function call it that
The following example illustrates this issue

```js
<script>
    var func = (function () {
        var check = function (value) {
            //detect caller function
            var that = arguments.callee.caller;

            //I want
            //if Buttom One click --> call print in func1 
            //if Buttom Two click --> call print in func2
        };

        return {
            check:check
        }
    })();

    var func1 = (function () {
        var start = function () {
            func.check(10);
        };
        var print = function (value) {
            alert(value);
        }

        return {
            start: start,
            print: print
        }
    })();

    var func2 ...
</script>
```

```html
<button id="One" onclick="func1.start()">One</button>
<button id="Two" onclick="func2.start()">Two</button>
```

Do you have a solution?
Many thanks!

Comment: `print` is not a property so can't be referenced as a property. Also, don't use `arguments.callee`, give your function a _name_. Yes, function expressions can have names too

Comment: Indeed, [arguments.callee is no longer part of the standard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript/235760#235760) and shouldn't be used anymore. As for Function.caller, [it was never standard to begin with](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller).

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Putting aside the fact that `arguments.callee` and `Function.caller` are both non-standard, the reason why it doesn't work is that you are confusing properties with local variables, all that mixed in with closures.

```
var func1 = (function () {
    // ...
})();
```

This creates a function, runs it and saves the result in `func1`. Since the return statement of your closure is `return { start: start }`, at the end of this section of code `func1` will contain an object which as a method called `start`.

When you use `var`, you're only creating a variable which exists inside that function. Outside of the function, it is no longer accessible. You did store the `start` function in the returned object, but you never returned `print` so it doesn't exist anymore.

Instead of going line by line and trying to explain all what is wrong, I'll ask you this: what you were actually trying to do? Don't ask us about your attempted solution which didn't work, but about what the code should do.

I suggest you look at these answers I wrote if you need further explanations on closures and scope.

[Understanding public/private instance variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832784/understanding-public-private-instance-variables/31834214#31834214)

[Do the different methods of creating classes in Javascript have names and what are they?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837294/do-the-different-methods-of-creating-classes-in-javascript-have-names-and-what-a/31838085#31838085)